# R: Making a new factor with new levels

Tags: r

I have a factor

```
factor <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
```

I want to make a new factor with levels one,two,three where

```
one = A,B  
two = C,D
three = E,F
```

So the new factor will look like

```
new_factor 
[1] one one two two three three
Levels: one two three
```

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2):

This is described in the help file for `?levels`:

```
x <- factor(LETTERS[1:6])
x
#[1] A B C D E F
#Levels: A B C D E F
levels(x) <- list("one" = c("A","B"), "two" = c("C","D"), "three" = c("E","F"))
x
#[1] one   one   two   two   three three
#Levels: one two three
```

Or if you don't want to overwrite the object:

```
`levels<-`(x, list("one" = c("A","B"), "two" = c("C","D"), "three" = c("E","F")))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gl` to create a grouping variable, `split` the `vector` with that and make it as a key/value `list`, `stack` it to create a `data.frame` and extract the 'ind' column

```
d1 <- stack(setNames(split(factor, as.numeric(gl(length(factor), 
             2, length(factor)))), c("one", "two", "three")))
new_factor <- factor(d1$ind, levels = c("one", "two", "three"))
new_factor
#[1] one   one   two   two   three three
#Levels: one two three
```

---

Or we can use `rep`

```
factor(rep(c('one', 'two', 'three'), each = 2), levels = c('one', 'two', 'three'))
```

#### Update

If the OP want to replace the specific elements "A", "B" with "one", "C", "D" with "two" instead of based on the position,

```
 set.seed(24)
 factor2 <- sample(LETTERS[1:6], 20, replace=TRUE)
 unname(setNames(rep(c("one", "two", "three"), each = 2), LETTERS[1:6])[factor2])
```

NOTE: Here, I assumed that the initial `vector` is `character` class.

Answer (score 1):

```
factor <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
names(factor) <- c(rep("one",2),rep("two",2),rep("three",2))
new_factor <- as.factor((names(factor)))
print(new_factor)
[1] one   one   two   two   three three
Levels: one three two
```

Comment: Logic may be the same, but coding approach is some what different

Comment: Its simple to use only single rep function rather than three times      names(factor) <- c(rep(c("one","two","three"),each=2))

Comment: yes, but i tried the one in different way

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `switch` (with `sapply` to loop through the vector).

```
 new.factor <- sapply(factor,  function(x) switch(x,
                      A = "one",
                      B = "one",
                      C = "two",
                      D = "two",
                      E = "three",
                      F = "three"))
```

You can then change it into a factor class object with `as.factor`.

```
new.factor <- as.factor(new.factor)
```